# Powershell shortcut to list all files and folders (including hidden files) and order them by date

Tags: powershell, windows-11, ls, dir

I'm basically looking for something like `ls -alt`, but in Powershell (Windows 11). Currently I'm using

```
gci -fo | sort LastWriteTime -Descending
```

but it's a bit of a doozy, and definitely not easy to remember. Isn't there anything shorter, which achieves the same?

**EDIT**: the proposed solution using

```
Function ls-alt {Invoke-Expression "gci $Args -Force"} # | sort LastWriteTime -Descending}
```

doesn't work. Proof:

1. create an empty dir with `mkdir test`
2. `cd test`
3. `notepad foo`, write some string (I wrote `string`), save and close
4. copy some older file into `test` (I used an existing `.gitconfig`, but I think any older file would work)
5. PS C:\Users\xxx\test> gci | sort LastWriteTime -Descending

   ```
    Directory: C:\Users\xxx\test
   ```

   Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name

   ---

   -a----         3/18/2024  10:04 PM              6 foo.txt
   -a----         8/31/2023   9:13 AM             66 .gitconfig
6. 

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\test> ls-alt


    Directory: C:\Users\xxx\test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/31/2023   9:13 AM             66 .gitconfig
-a----         3/18/2024  10:04 PM              6 foo.txt
```

The proposed solution doesn't correctly order files by `LastWriteTime`. The content of the profile file is as expected:

```
notepad $PROFILE
Function ls-alt {Invoke-Expression "gci $Args -Force"} # | sort LastWriteTime -Descending}
```

Comment: Why not define it as a function in your profile? Then you can give it any name you want, i.e. `Function ls-alt {gci -force | sort LastWriteTime -Descending}`.

Comment: ...and if you want it to take parameters, esaentially acting like a customized `gci`, use: `Function ls-alt {Invoke-expression "gci $Args -Force"} # | sort LastWriteTime -Descending}`. That will allow `ls-alt -s` (Recurse), `ls-alt $HOME`, etc.

Comment: @KeithMiller You should convert your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a customized version of a Cmdlet or a series of actions accessible with minimal typing, define it as a function in your **PowerShell** profile -- then it will be available in every console session you run.

A simple version would wrap your example verbatim:

```
Function ls-alt {gci -force | sort LastWriteTime -Descending}
```

But this limits its to the current directory with none of the familiar options of filtering, recursion, etc.

To have your customizations as the defaults *and* retain the use of positional parameters, named parameters, and aliases native to [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4), you can define it using [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.4://) and the [$Args](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4#args) *automatic variable*:

```
Function ls-alt {Invoke-Expression "gci $Args -Force" | sort LastWriteTime -Descending}
```

That will allow `ls-alt -s` (Recurse), `ls-alt $HOME`, etc.

Comment: nice! Where do I write this instruction? In other words, where is the PowerShell profile? Do I need to be an admin to edit it?

Comment: @DeltaIV: no, you don't need to be an advent. In PowerShell type `notepad $PROFILE`. If you don't have a profile, you'll be creating it by adding this function and just save the file. Launch a new console and your function it should be available

Comment: It doesn't work. Please have a look at my edited question.

Comment: I just looked at my answer a pound sign crept into the code and commented out the sort in the function definition try it with the fixed version

Comment: Should have told you to test it in the console first -- you would get the continuation prompt waiting for the closing bracket...

Comment: it still doesn't work. Did you test it? `At C:\Users\xxx\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:1 char:56
+ Function ls-alt {Invoke-Expression "gci $Args -Force"} | sort LastWri ...
+                                                        ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At C:\Users\xxxl\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:1 char:88
+ ... voke-Expression "gci $Args -Force"} | sort LastWriteTime -Descending}
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.`

Comment: I was unable to test (until now) because I edited & replied from my phone in an attempt to respoind in a timely manner. That doesn't play well with the fact that I'm f'ing legally blind. Didn't need to test as much as I needed to see and use an actaul keyboard!!!  You're welcome in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could have known about that. A simple "I'll get back to you tomorrow, once I have access to a pc" would have sufficed. Anyway, it works now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DeltaIV: You're welcome. I didn't expect you to know any of that --- just giving xontext to the two previous versions with embarrassingly obvious syntax errors that (I like to think) I would have caught under (what passes for) normal circumstances. B⁠-⁠)